# Fazer consulta SQL com subquery usando where com aspas

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer um `SELECT` com uma subquery onde o campo que está no `where` da subquery é um campo da tabela principal. 
Porém, este campo precisa estar entre aspas simples e quando faço isso, o mysql interpreta como uma string e não um campo. Exemplo:

```
SELECT t.id, t.code, t.name, 
   (select date 
    from positions pt 
    where pt.code = 't.code' 
    order by date asc limit 1) as position
FROM trips t
```

Entendam que o campo t.code é o campo vindo da tabela principal. O campo precisa estar entre aspas simples, senão o `Mysql` não consegue realizar a consulta.

Comment: Porque o campo precisa estar em aspas simples?

Comment: Este campo é um índice. Quando não utilizo ele entre aspas simples o Mysql entende como um valor inteiro e não realiza a consulta. Quando coloco as aspas ele entende como uma string e consulta normalmente, mesmo os campos sendo do tipo INT.

Comment: Estou testando no sqlserver e funciona normalmente sem aspas, mas não consegui validar no mysql. Pra mim deveria funcionar sem as aspas. Aparece algum erro?

Comment: A minha tabela tem uma quantidade muito grande de registros, uns 6 milhões mais ou menos. Quando eu uso sem aspas, eu dou um Explain e vejo que ele faz a busca nos 6 milhões, mas quando coloco aspas, dá pra ver q ele faz a busca pegando pelo índice e realiza a busca.

Comment: E porque você não faz um inner join?

Comment: Já tentei fazer Join, mas mesmo assim cai na mesmo situação do código em aspas simples.

Comment: Mas então @bruno eu não entendo porque precisa estar em aspas simples. Talvez eu não tenho entendido seu problema. Veja este exemplo funcionando perfeitamente: https://paiza.io/projects/plLZovf48aOOFZGROg3c9w?language=mysql sem aspas